# Django Creating Custom User models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am making a website through Django and I want to create a similar model for the Users model (default user model came with Django)
I have tried everything I have found from google django docs and I couldn't.

Can anyone help?
Or help me to make a login system for my normal model

For an instance,
I have created a normal model called `accounts` and there is a field in it called `loggedin`.
Whenever I try to login system set it to `True` means logged in. And if i logged out by the logout button i set it to false now lets take in consideration if i have closed the web browser Immediately i want to set it to `False` 
Any help?

Answer (score 3):

There are two common ways to deal with is extending django's `AbstractUser`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    # Some other fields to go along with the default fields
    info = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

> After this, just change the default user model on your `settings.py` adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = my_app.models.user`

Comment: I can now use all the methods like authenticate()¿

Comment: Yes. You see, you are just extending django's default user. Your user model will have all fields and all methods from de parent user, plus the new ones you add.